# Pthreads: Main overwrites mutex lock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am fairly new in threads programming and I wanted to test the mutex functionality. So I programmed the following in order to test it.

**thread_test.h

```
...
extern int flags;
extern pthread_mutex my_mutex;
...
```

**thread_test.c

```
...
#include"thread_test.h"
...    
void * thread_test(void *thread_parameters)
{
long tid = (long) thread_parameters;

pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
++flags;
printf("**THREAD %d** started. Flag value is %d.\n",tid, flags);
sleep(6);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);

pthread_exit(NULL);
}
...
```

**main.c

```
...
#include"thread_test.h"
...
#define THREADS 5
pthread_t threads[THREADS];
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
int     flags = 0;
...
int main(){
int rct;
for(rct = 0; rct<THREADS; rct++)
if(pthread_create(&threads[rct],NULL, thread_test, (void *)rct))
   printf("ERROR!")
else
   {
   sleep(1);
   printf("Thread %d initialised in main and the flags value is %d.\n", rct,flags);
   }

pthread_mutex_destroy(&my_mutex);
...
```

It appears that even though I lock the mutex in the child threads, the main program somehow overwrites the mutex lock while a thread has it and assigns variable flags with a new value..

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Most likely, `main()` is getting to the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` before any of the threads even get a chance to run (and I'm not sure `pthread_mutex_destroy()` really even cares if the mutex is locked or not...). You should probably `pthread_join()` all your threads before you destroy the mutex...

Comment: `main()` changes the flag variable already as the first thread is in `sleep(6)` and before it destroys the mutex.The output looks like that:
`**THREAD 0** started.The current flag is 1.`
`Thread 0 initialized in main and the flag value is : 1`
`Thread 1 initialized in main and the flag value is : 1`
`Thread 2 initialized in main and the flag value is : 2`
`Thread 3 initialized in main and the flag value is : 3`
`Thread 4 initialized in main and the flag value is : 4`
`**THREAD 1** started.The current flag is 5.`
`**THREAD 2** started.The current flag is 6.`
...
etc..

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you have several errors in your code, part of which your compiler should have told you if you switch all warnings on.

- `pthread_mutex_t` variables must be initialized. For static initialization using `= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` at the point of defininition would be enough. (And there is not much point in destroying a static mutex on the other end.)
- in the code snippet you gave there is no declaration of `thread_test` visible to `main`
- you exit `main` (and destroy the mutex) before the threads have terminated. You may do this, but then you'd have to use an explit `pthread_exit` in `main` (and definitively don't do the destroy then). The commonly used approach is not to do this, but to use `pthread_join` for all threads that have been created.

Also, you could indent your code before posting here, that would much help to make it more readable.